# Entity Framework bug with query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have an array with this data (`ID`, `Time`, and `Name`):

```
var array = new[]
{
    new { ID = 1, Time = DateTime.ParseExact("12:01", "HH:mm", null), Name = "Peter" },
    new { ID = 2, Time = DateTime.ParseExact("12:06", "HH:mm", null), Name = "James" }, 
    new { ID = 3, Time = DateTime.ParseExact("12:03", "HH:mm", null), Name = "Jackie" },
    new { ID = 4, Time = DateTime.ParseExact("12:08", "HH:mm", null), Name = "Peter" }, 
    new { ID = 5, Time = DateTime.ParseExact("12:05", "HH:mm", null), Name = "James" },
    new { ID = 6, Time = DateTime.ParseExact("12:07", "HH:mm", null), Name = "Peter" },
};
```

The following statement on the array produces the correct result:

```
var result = array.OrderBy(x => x.Time).GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                  .SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

The result:

```
Time: 2013/3/6 12:01:00, Name: Peter
Time: 2013/3/6 12:07:00, Name: Peter
Time: 2013/3/6 12:08:00, Name: Peter
Time: 2013/3/6 12:03:00, Name: Jackie
Time: 2013/3/6 12:05:00, Name: James
Time: 2013/3/6 12:06:00, Name: James
```

But when I use the same statement with EF and SQL Server, the order is wrong:

```
Time: 2013/3/6 12:03:00, Name: Jackie
Time: 2013/3/6 12:06:00, Name: James
Time: 2013/3/6 12:05:00, Name: James
Time: 2013/3/6 12:07:00, Name: Peter
Time: 2013/3/6 12:01:00, Name: Peter
Time: 2013/3/6 12:08:00, Name: Peter
```

Here is the SQL EF generates:

```
SELECT 
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent2].[Time] AS [Time], 
[Extent2].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM [dbo].[testt1] AS [Extent1] ) AS [Distinct1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[testt1] AS [Extent2]
ON ([Distinct1].[Name] = [Extent2].[Name]) OR 
   (([Distinct1].[Name] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[Name] IS NULL))
```

There is no `order by` clause.

1. What did I forget? Is this a bug of EF?
2. How to get the same result from EF as from the array?

Comment: Just had to say: This is a very well asked question. You have code to reproduce (at least in linq to objects), expected output, actual output, generated SQL, and even good formatting. Keep it up!

Answer (score 3):

Just like in SQL:

First group, then order:

```
var result = array.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                  .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Time))
                  .SelectMany(x => x)
                  .ToArray();
```

But in your case I don't see why you would need the group at all. Every time seems to be different, so a simpler version that yields the same result (at least with your test data) would be:

```
var result = array.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                  .ThenBy(y => y.Time)
                  .ToArray();
```